# Calculate currents in thevenin equivalent methods

Tags: thevenin, kirchhoffs-laws

I have this circuit that I am trying to solve for the short circuit current.

[image]

I am not extremely strong with analyzing circuits (this is finding the short circuit current for a Thevenin equivalent), but I tried solving for currents two different ways and  am still wrong. I performed mesh analysis using the three squares as loops which yields these three equations (the left loop is 1, the middle is 2, the right is 3):

10*(I1-I2)=0

10*(I1-I2)+12+40*(I3-I2)=0

40*(I3-I2)-5*I3=0

which gives: I1=2.1, I2=2.1, I3=2.4

Then I used the middle and rights loops using KVL with the current labelled as in the picture:

12-40*Ia-10*Ib=0

-5Isc+40*Ia=0

Ia+Ib+Isc=4.5*Ia

which gives Ia=2.4, Ib=-10.8, Isc=19.2

I understand the solution that they give (and I can post it but someone who is familiar with this probably doesn't need it), but what I don't understand is why my methods did not work and why they picked their particular method/loops to evaluate (it could also stem from the fact that I have not analyzed many circuits so I am inexperienced at how to approach).

Thanks!

This is the solution as given:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You begin with an incorrect statement:
$$10(I_1-I_2)=0$$

You're saying that the voltage across the current controlled current source is 0 which is very likely incorrect. You can say $$10(I_1-I_2) = V_\text{node_between_CCCS_and_12Vsource}$$

But you can't assume that that voltage equals 0. If you have some current flowing through that resistor, then the voltage can **not** be 0.

Other than that, your equations look good. These should be them:

$$ 4.5\times I_a = I_1 $$

$$ 10(I_1-I_2)+12+40*(I_3-I_2)=0  $$
$$ 40\times(I_3-I_2)-5I_3=0  $$
$$ I_a = I_2-I_3  $$

4 equations and 4 unknowns. You should be golden to solve it from here.

Comment: So then you cannot use a mesh on the left circuit with the independent current source?

Comment: @Prevost I would still call it mesh analysis. It's just that you already "know" your I1 current because the dependent current source tells you that it's 4.5*Ia. Maybe it's just a po-tae-toe/po-ta-toe thing in terms of what you call it. Also, just a clarification, it's a *dependent* current source rather than an independent one.

Comment: @Prevost Yup, definitely still mesh analysis according to wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis#Setting_up_the_equations
Also, you should read up how to use super-meshes there so that you can handle a current source that actually shares two loops.

Comment: My bad, it is a dependent current source. Okay, then I guess where I don't understand it is that if I used mesh analysis, I would not use the 4.5*Ia=I1 and instead would use 4.5*I1=I2...and then once I solved for I1,I2,I3 then I would find the actual current through the resistors (which would be equal to Ia, Ib, Isc). And also can you please explain this equation further  10*(I1-I2) = V_node_between_CCCS_and_12Vsource. I would not get that from my Mesh analysis (even though I agree that my original equation was wrong).

Comment: Would you use a super mesh that combines the middle loop with the right loop (and doesn't include the 40 ohm resistor)?

Comment: @Prevost You should be more explicit. You mean 4.5Ia=I2 +(I1-I2)? I just directly reduced that down to 4.5Ia=I1. You wouldn't use a supermesh here, that's only for use when a current source is between two loops.
For the other equation I gave: If you use ohms law over the 10 ohm resistor while still using mesh analysis, you have the voltage at the negative side of the 12V Source equals 10*(I1-I2). I.e. V=IR where I=I1-I2 and R = 10.

Comment: When I asked this question I was completely new to node and mesh analysis. The textbook 'Introduction To Electric Circuits' 9th Edition by Svoboda & Dorf offers an explanation of independent/dependent current and voltage sources and how to deal with them in node and mesh analysis in Chapter 4.